# Message not sending to user when on_message issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Hi I'm having an issue when sending a message from a channel to a users direct messages. The message when using @user followed by message should DM the user I'm not sure why this is not working.

The mention in the message should take the user object.

Here is the code:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    """Send a message thread reply to user."""
    for member in message.mentions: #get user object from mention in message?
        if not member.dm_channel: 
            await member.create_dm()
        try:
            time = datetime.utcnow()
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Reply", timestamp=time, colour=discord.Colour(0xff8100))
            embed.add_field(name="Message:", value="test message")
            await member.dm_channel.send(embed=embed)
        except discord.Forbidden:
            await message.channel.send(f"Reply cannot be sent because {member.name}'s direct messages are set to private.")
        except discord.HTTPException:
            await message.channel.send('I failed in sending the message.')
        except Exception as e:
            await message.channel.send(f'There\'s been a problem while sending the message that\'s not of type "Forbidden" or'
                       f' "HTTPException", but {e}.')
        else:
            await message.channel.send(f'Reply sent to {member.name}')
```

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: Sending a message from a text channel to a users direct messages using user mention. No error but issue in code preventing message to be sent to the users DM.

Comment: You might want to try change @commands.Cog.listener() to @client.event or whatever you set to your bot instance to.

Comment: This is a cog so to register an event from a new-style cog, I must use the commands.Cog.listener decorator to listen for events. @client.event wouldn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In discord.py you don't really have to create dm channels anymore. Just do a `await ctx.author.send(# whatever message you want)`
If you're trying to create a command that sends a **SPECIFIC DM** to the **author of the message**, you can try this

```
@client.command()
async def dm(ctx, *, message):
    await ctx.author.send(f"This is your dm {message}")
```

It's extremely simple. Let me know in the comments if you have any questions or I misunderstood your problem.

EDIT:
If you're looking to send a dm to a **SPECIFIC MEMBER**, you can try this.

```
@client.command()
async def dm(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, message):
    await member.send(message)
```

Hope your problem has been solved.

**PS: In the future, please explain your questions/issues in more detail.**